# Is there a tutorial on how to use JEditTextArea in my application?

Tags: java, jedit

I'm trying to embed the JEditTextArea into my application, which is available here: http://syntax.jedit.org/

I was wondering if there was a definitive guide to doing this?  I am having problems getting the packages to work, and am not sure how I'm supposed to even go about importing them into my project.  If anyone has gotten this to work, or has a better solution to getting syntax highlighting in my application, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This extra package seems to be dead since 2002.
I was not even aware this exists as separate project.
If you want to embed the JEditTextArea, you should use the recent version.
For this you would have to take the source distribution and call "ant build-textArea" which should produce the independent TextArea to be embedded in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing then perhaps [StyledDocument](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) is for you? I've used it for syntax highlighting in applications and it was relatively painless.